# Error on open image in page (Open as base64)

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a gridview with pjax, which does the listing of images. But when you click on the image to open it, it opens it in the base64 format (everything is encoded on the page).

How to correct?

**Viewing the image**
[image]
**After clicking**
[image]

**UPDATED POST page.php**

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'pjax-container']) ?>
            <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'emptyText'    => '</br><p class="text-danger">Nenhum imagem anexada!</p>',
            'summary'      =>  '',
            'showHeader'   => false,
            'columns' => [
                    [
                    'attribute'=>'img',
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'value'=>function ($data) {
                        return Html::a(Html::img(\Yii::$app->getModule('client')->params['clientImages'].$data["mod_client_base_id"].'/'.$data["img"],
                             ['width' => '50px', 'class' => 'img-rounded img-responsive']), \Yii::$app->getModule('client')->params['clientImages'].$data["mod_client_base_id"].'/'.$data["img"], ['data-method'=>'post','target' => '_blank']);
                    },                                     
                    'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 70%;text-align:left'],
                    ],
                    [
                    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                    'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 30%;text-align:center'],
                    'controller' => 'images',
                    'template' => ' {delete}',
                    'buttons' => [
                            'delete' => function ($url) {
                            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                              'title' => 'Excluir Imagem',
                              'class' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm',
                              'aria-label' => 'Excluir',
                              'onclick' => "
                                  if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir?')) {
                                      $.ajax('$url', {
                                          type: 'POST'
                                      }).done(function(data) {
                                          $.pjax.reload({container: '#pjax-container'});
                                      });
                                  }
                                  return false;
                              ",
                            ]);
                            },
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

Comment: fix with param: 'data-method'=>'post'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix with: `'data-method'=>'post'`

```
[
                    'attribute'=>'img',
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'value'=>function ($data) {
                        return Html::a(Html::img(\Yii::$app->getModule('client')->params['clientImages'].$data["mod_client_base_id"].'/'.$data["img"],
                             ['width' => '50px', 'class' => 'img-rounded img-responsive']), \Yii::$app->getModule('client')->params['clientImages'].$data["mod_client_base_id"].'/'.$data["img"], ['data-method'=>'post','target' => '_blank']);
                    },                                     
                    'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 70%;text-align:left'],
                    ],
```